# Query count of sub documents based on condition in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection where a sample document has the following shape:

```
{
  "document_1": {
    "field_1": {},
    "array_1": {
      "subobject_1": {
        "subobject_field_1": "true",
        "subobject_field_2": {},
        "subobject_field_3": {}
      },
      "subobject_2": {
        "subobject_field_1": "false",
        "subobject_field_2": {},
        "subobject_field_3": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The number of subobjects (`subobject_`) under `array_1` varies and is not the same for all documents. I am trying to make a query that, for each document, counts the number of subobjects where `subobject_field_1` is `true`. I also want to be able to specify exactly which fields to return, and set additional conditions (in this case the additional condition would be that `field_1 = "A"`). In this case, the output would look like:

```
{
  "document_1": {
    "field_1": "A",
    "array_1": 1
  }
}
```

I have tried the code below, but that only gives me the number of subobjects regardless of whether or not `subobject_field_1`is `true`or `false`.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
{
    $match: {field_1: 'A'}
    },
{
    $project: {field_1: 1, array_1: {$size: $array_1}}
    }
])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "field_1": "A" }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "field_2": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": { "$objectToArray": "$field_2" },
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.v.subdoc_field_1", "true"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, where is the 'A' condition on field_1 in you example?

Comment: Has put it now... Also, you got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719488/query-the-count-of-sub-elements-with-condition-in-mongo-db

Comment: I get "$objectToArray requires a document input, found: array" when I try this. It seems like I misspecified the question (sorry for that). So the subdocuments are actually arrays. I will edit the question, but how can I adapt your answer to be valid for the case with subarrays as well?

Comment: Actually, field_2 is an array including subobjects.

Comment: Please show your actual documents by copying direct from the mongo-shell

Comment: The real document is very messy so I am trying to keep it clean (apparently unsuccessfully...). But it should be correct now: field_2 is an array containing objects. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: If field_2 is an array then pls edit your question and correct it.

Comment: I guess I just need to delete the "input" row? However, this returns every element of the document, instead of only field_1 and array_1.

Comment: Also, I can see that array_1 returns a zero in all cases, even when there are subobject_field_1 with a true value.